# python pandas keep updating certain columns while merge with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert

I have several dataframes and want to insert new column and keep updating first data frame's that column.

```
df1

    OCC_99  NAICS_2002  NAICS_2010  NAICS_2016  
0   19002   Nan         Nan         Nan
1   19005   Nan         Nan         Nan
2   19003   Nan         Nan         Nan
3   19004   Nan         Nan         Nan
4   19006   Nan         Nan         Nan
5   Nan     Nan         11-1011     Nan
6   Nan     Nan         11-1023     Nan
7   Nan     Nan         11-2021     Nan
8   Nan     Nan         Nan         Nan
9   Nan     Nan         Nan         Nan
10  Nan     Nan         Nan         Nan


df2

    soccode oescode oes99code
0   11-1011 19002   11-1011
1   11-1012 19005   11-1012
2   11-1013 19004   11-1021
3   11-1014 19003   11-1023
4   11-1015 19006   11-1025
```

then match with `df1['OCC_99']` to `df2['oescode']` and insert the values from `df2['soccode']` to `df1['NAICS_2012]`.
I want to generate `df1` like below in first step.

```
    OCC_99  NAICS_2002  NAICS_2010  NAICS_2016  NAICS_2012
0   19002   Nan         Nan         Nan         11-1011
1   19005   Nan         Nan         Nan         11-1012
2   19003   Nan         Nan         Nan         11-1014
3   19004   Nan         Nan         Nan         11-1013
4   19006   Nan         Nan         Nan         11-1015
5   Nan     Nan         11-1011     Nan         Nan
6   Nan     Nan         11-1023     Nan         Nan
7   Nan     Nan         11-2021     Nan         Nan
8   Nan     11-1012     Nan         Nan         Nan
9   Nan     11-1013     Nan         Nan         Nan
10  Nan     11-1014     Nan         Nan         Nan
```

and then I will use `df3`,

```
    code02  code12  
0   11-1011 11-2022
1   11-1012 11-3035
2   11-1013 11-4031
3   11-1014 11-2024
4   11-1015 11-2033
```

then, math with `df1['NAICS_2002']` to `df3['code02']` and insert `df3['code12']` to `df1['NAICS_2012']`.
I want to generate `df1` like below in second step.

```
    OCC_99  NAICS_2002  NAICS_2010  NAICS_2016  NAICS_2012
0   19002   Nan         Nan         Nan         11-1011
1   19005   Nan         Nan         Nan         11-1012
2   19003   Nan         Nan         Nan         11-1014
3   19004   Nan         Nan         Nan         11-1013
4   19006   Nan         Nan         Nan         11-1015
5   Nan     Nan         11-1011     Nan         Nan
6   Nan     Nan         11-1023     Nan         Nan
7   Nan     Nan         11-2021     Nan         Nan
8   Nan     11-1012     Nan         Nan         11-3035
9   Nan     11-1013     Nan         Nan         11-4031
10  Nan     11-1014     Nan         Nan         11-2024
```

I used the function like below, but when I used the same newcolname everytime, it keep generate separate columns with same column names in dataframe so it could not keep updating same column.

```
df_new = (df1.merge(df2[[df2col1,df2col2]], left_on=df1col,
            right_on = df2col1, how='left').drop(df2col1, axis=1)\
          .rename(columns={df2col2:newcolname}))
```

Comment: try look at `map`

Comment: Can you try to explain more clearly what you are trying to accomplish (with the merges and calculations).

Comment: @Josh Basically I want to add new column 'NAICS_2012' to df1 and keep updating the new corresponding values compare df1 and df2 and 'df1' and 'df3'. Here, the column names do not match each other but the values match each other so I need to merge using specific column name. What I want to try is like VLOOKUP function in excel.